# How can I disable watchdog in U-boot using mw command

Tags: hardware, serial-communication

So I have DVR with `2*Hi3511RBC CPU: ARM926EJ-Sid(wb) [41069265] revision 5 (ARMv5TEJ)` and when I enter U-boot (how do I know that I'm in U-boot ? ) well over UART I get following message

```
U-Boot 1.1.4 (Nov 17 2008 - 19:48:18)

U-Boot code: E0500000 -> E05174C0  BSS: -> E051E23C
HI_VERSION=U_BOOT_1_1_4-M06C0303B0301 @Hi3511v110_OSDrv_1_0_0_1 2008-11-03 18:27:45
RAM Configuration:
Bank #0: e0000000 256 MB
## Unknown FLASH on Bank 1 - Size = 0x00000000 = 0 MB
Flash:  0 kB
*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
MAC:   00-00-00-00-00-00
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  1
```

and I press any key and I get following

```
hilinux # ?
?       - alias for 'help'
base    - print or set address offset
bdinfo  - print Board Info structure
bootm   - boot application image from memory
bootp   - boot image via network using BootP/TFTP protocol
cmp     - memory compare
cp      - memory copy
crc32   - checksum calculation
dhcp    - invoke DHCP client to obtain IP/boot params
echo    - echo args to console
erase   - erase FLASH memory
flinfo  - print FLASH memory information
go      - start application at address 'addr'
help    - print online help
loadb   - load binary file over serial line (kermit mode)
loop    - infinite loop on address range
md      - memory display
mm      - memory modify (auto-incrementing)
mtest   - simple RAM test
mw      - memory write (fill)
nm      - memory modify (constant address)
ping    - send ICMP ECHO_REQUEST to network host
printenv- print environment variables
protect - enable or disable FLASH write protection
rarpboot- boot image via network using RARP/TFTP protocol
reset   - Perform RESET of the CPU
saveenv - save environment variables to persistent storage
setenv  - set environment variables
tftp    - download or upload image via network using TFTP protocol
version - print monitor version
```

the after some time 10-15 sec. device just reboots and I cant dump content of ram with `md.b` command so one guy suggested me that I can disable watchdog with `mw` command when I'm in U-boot so I just need to find which register to alter. I have little experience with this stuff can someone take a look at datasheet and figure out command for this ? Datasheet can be accessed at link https://mega.nz/file/9c4CVK6T#P78EU3Yrt2oUr2El_78M7Bp3EjzNiT8HFtr5HOuUrLw

Edit: Add printenv

```
hilinux # printenv
bootargs=mem=32M console=ttyAMA0,115200
bootcmd=bootm 0xe1000000 0xe1500000
bootdelay=1
baudrate=115200
ethaddr=00:00:00:00:00:00
ipaddr=192.168.1.10
serverip=192.168.1.1
netmask=255.255.255.0
bootfile="uImage"
stdin=serial
stdout=serial
stderr=serial
verify=n

Environment size: 261/131068 bytes
```

Comment: What is the final goal (i.e. what do you want to dump, RAM, firmware ..)? "and when I enter U-boot the device reboots" - What does that mean? You are able to get into uboot (How?) and the device reboots automatically at some later point?

Comment: @secfren `when I enter U-boot` mean that when the device powers on I got message "Hit any key to stop autoboot:  1 " over UART/Serial communication and then I hit any key after which I  get prompt `hilinux #` on my UART console, that means that Im in U-boot mode and yes device reboots automatically at some later point

Comment: printenv output? The timeout is consistent? Sry, cant help you with the registers. u-boot has a config option + command option to enable/disable the timer https://u-boot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/cmd/wdt.html but at least the latter does not seem to be available. It looks like there could be some uboot sources available for your device on some chinese forums. There may be also some alternative ways to get RAM (JTAG) in case your board supports that.

Comment: @secfren I added printenv. Yes reboots are constant. It has 16 pin header but logic is at 5v so I cant use jtagulator for example. Can you give me a link of mine U-boot source files on those chinese forums ? TNX

Comment: I could not find sources for the model itself but this thread mentions modifying the respective u-boot https://bbs.16rd.com/thread-566203-1-1.html potential sources once available here: http://bbs.ntpcb.com/read.php?tid=30884&fpage=11&skinco=wind8green . I did not look to deep but a google search on " Hi3511_VSSDK_V1.1.2.3" or "hi3511 u-boot"  also indicated more related threads. Maybe you are lucky. Sources for newer models can be found on github https://github.com/Axl-zhang/hisilicon-hi3520d-uboot/